# MYSQL phpmyadmin Error updating / adding User Accounts

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, synology

First apologies in advance if this is not appropriate, this is the first question from a long time fan!

I'm using phpMyAdmin When I try and update an existing user account, or create a new one I get this error message

[image]

When click through to edit the SQL this is the statement it is trying to run:

```
SHOW PLUGINS SONAME LIKE '%_password_check%'
```

I'm running MariaDB 5.5.52-0069 on a synology box. All stock. I used to be able to update user accounts etc, so I think I started getting the error messages when Synology updated PHP 5.6.28-0036 and phpMyAdmin (within a few minutes of each other) on 6-Dec-16. Details of the server follow:

[image]

I'm sure I'm missing a bunch of relevant information, but I don't know enough to know what I could be missing.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTTTW.jpg):

Comment: Missing where keyword??

Comment: Try: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE '%password%';`  I think it's phpmyadmin's issue.

Comment: the SQL statement given by num8er works fine. Returns 2 rows, with plugin_name  mysql_native_password and my_sql_old_password.

Comment: I've opened a bug report about this issue at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's phpMyAdmin's issue.

Work directly with mysql:

Find Your user in list:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'username';
```

Then if exist:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'username';
```

Then create user:

```
GRANT ALL ON database_name_here.* TO 'username'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
GRANT ALL ON database_name_here.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 12):

Just create a folder `lib` under MySQL main folder and create sub-folder call `plugin` and it solved.

Comment: More a workaround than a solution but thanks for sharing. It helped with my XAMPP 5.6.30.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue too, I clicked the generate password, deleted it and replaced it with a text password and then later pressed the "go" button and got that error. I am guessing that it is a password mismatch error.

Next, I tried a plain text password but got some message saying that "xampp\mysql\lib\plugin" was not found.

Solution:
Went into xampp>mysql, created "lib" folder, went into "lib" folder and created "plugin" folder and tried creating a user again and now user creation works using phpmyadmin.

Note that I use xampp. Funny thing is that nothing is created "plugin" folder as if it was never needed but still required for user creation.

Comment: This is the proper solution, at least in my case saved the day! thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you! Would have been pulling my hair out over that for ages for what was a fairly straightforward fix.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been a problem with phpMyAdmin 4.6.5. It will be fixed in the next release (which will probably be 4.6.6 and is expected in January); in the mean time you can apply the patch from https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/eeb016bf4df26f6927c1dd233b94f62d94c0e398.patch which should resolve the issue for you.